# How can I maintain an Airplay connection?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, airplay

I'm working on a Mac Mini home automation server that I'm trying to get to send text-to-speech messages to an Airport Express connected Airplay speaker.

My problem is that I can't get it to maintain its connection to the Airplay speaker.

I've tried running this AppleScript at intervals but the problem persists:

```
tell application "Airfoil"
  connect to every speaker
end tell
```

Even Airfoil seems to lose its connection after an hour or so.

How can I force a constant Airplay connection?